# Increase the default memory limit for electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

How to increase the default memory limit for electron app?
`--max-old-space-size` flag does not seem to have any effect?
App getting crashed when rss(Resident Set Size ) size reaches 1gb

Comment: Please specify the versions of electron, node.js etc that you're using.

Comment: How did you find the default v8 memory limit for electron app?